# Why did I get this result using a for loop? [Java]

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a question about the following code.

```
public class test
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++); {
        b = b + a;
        a++;
    }
    System.out.println(b);
```

Why is the output of this 0? As you can see I'm a complete beginner but why does it not go through the loop 4 times before printing the answer?

Help is appreciated!

//Confused beginner

Comment: syntax error - you have a semi colon after the `for` before your curly brace.

Answer (score 1):

For loops iterate over the statement or block immediately following the for statement.  In this case you have a stray semicolon causing the next statement to be empty.  Remove it and your code will work as indended

Replace:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++); { 
    b = b + a;
    a++;
}
```

-with-

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    b = b + a;
    a++;
}
```

Comment: Problems caused by typographical errors should be closed, not answered.  This one probably will be soon.  D.B. did the correct thing by answering in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, I'm relitively new here.

Comment: Is it appropriate to delete the answer?

Comment: @DavidWallace Since when?

Comment: @Unamanic No, don't do that. Even if closed, your answer stays and is helpful to other people. Besides, you still get to keep any points you earned through effort of providing an answer.

Comment: @SnakeDoc since always.  Click the _close_ link and have a look at the list of reasons under the _off topic_ option.

Answer (score 1):

It does not return 0. In does not return anything as there are mistakes in your code.

After the for loop, there is no ;

```
public static void main(String[] args){   

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        b = b + a;
        a++;
    }
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Comment: The OP's code is valid, though not useful.  The loop executes and empty statement 5 times, executes the code block once, and outputs 0.  Many IDE's flag this mistake, however. edit: missing trailing '}'s aside.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the semicolon after the for loop statement, otherwise the body surrounded by the curly braces will not be considered under the for loop.

Replace the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++); {
                           ^ <--- remove it  
    b = b + a;
    a++;
}
```

by

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++); {
    b = b + a;
    a++;
}
```